# How to get solar zenith angle using pysolar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, solar

I'm using [pysolar](https://pysolar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to get the `Solar Zenith Angle`. I was verifying the data from [NOAA](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/antuv/SolarCalc.jsp) solar calculator. I was thinking if there's a way to add the timezone in `get_altitude` method. I calculated the `SZA` without using any timezone but it varies too much from what NOAA calculator shows. The below code is for `Dubai`. Timezone: `Asia/Dubai`.

```
from pysolar.solar import *
import datetime

dobj = datetime.datetime(2017,7,20,7,0)
sza = float(90)-get_altitude(25.0657, 55.17128, dobj)
print (sza)
```

The output is: `93.11938274977194` . But NOAA shows the SZA at 7 AM should be `132.88884`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong  ?

Comment: You are using `datetime(...` with `tzinfo=None`How do you know it's using `Timezone: Asia/Dubai`?

Answer (score 1):

Dubai is in timezone UTC+4, so we need to adjust Dubai time to UTC time. The default time zone is your computer timezone, depending on your location and setting.

So I get result of 73.9 with following codes. It make senses that in the morning you expect the sun is close to the horizon.

```
dobj = datetime.datetime(2017,7,20,7,tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
sza = float(90) - get_altitude(25.0657, 55.17128, dobj)
print ("timezone = UTC+4,",sza)
```